# Multivariable version of the extreme value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The Wikipedia entry on the [extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)
says that if $f$ is a real-valued continuous function
on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$,
then $f$ must attain a maximum value,
i.e. there exists an $x \in [a,b]$
such that $f(x) \geq f(y)$ for all $y \in [a,b]$.

I think that there is a more general version of the extreme value theorem
which states a similar result for a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
(At least I think I remember hearing about this in a class on metric spaces.)
Is there a statement of this more general version of the theorem,
hopefully with a reference as well?

Comment: The general thing is compactness. A continuous function on a [non-empty] compact space attains its maximum (and minimum). That's because a continuous image of a compact space is compact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, in fact they both come from two standard results in analysis:

Theorem 1: A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Theorem 2: Continuous image of a compact set is a compact set.

Corollary: Given $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and bounded. By Theorem 1, $A$ is compact. Hence $f(A)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So $f(A)$ is closed and bounded. That proves the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: We need a theorem saying that the closed and bounded set $B:=f(A)\subset{\mathbb R}$ has a maximal element.

Answer (score 1):

There is [this](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Murphy.pdf) document that states the theorem even more générally:

Theorem 3.4. (The Extreme Value Theorem) If $f : X \to R$ is real valued **[edit: and continuous]** function
from a compact space to the real numbers, then f attains a greatest value, that is
there is an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \geq f(y)$ for all $y \in X$.

Comment: In proof of Theorem 3.4 the Lemma 3.1 is used (but not referenced with name). In the lemma 3.1 f is correctly required to be continuous. Thus is should be included in Theorem 3.4 that f is required to be continuous.

Comment: Thanks, dioid, I've edited my post